# Make diff between two branches from Git and Mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial

I have two repositories. One is Git repository. And other is Mercurial repository.
Is it possible to show difference between two branches between two repositories?

Comment: Check out the branches you want to compare and use your favorite diff tool to compare the directory trees? If that's not good enough, please be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have both a git and hg repo in the same directory. You need to be a bit clever about the appropriate ignore files so you don't have one repo tracking the repo data for the other, but it is possible. This allows you to use git or hg diff to compare the current code to both repos.

There are plugins that will allow you to hg pull and push from remote git repos.

http://hg-git.github.io/